# Wordpress loop not working on blog.php page

Tags: theme-development

Well, i'm creating a wordpress theme, but i can't get wordpress loop to work correctly for some reason. This code works fine in index.php :

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      var_dump($post);
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

But, it does not work in my blog.php page(it's not a template, it's actually a shortcode).
The shortcode works correctly for sure. But when the above code is executed it just prints NULL. If i try to grab the_content, the page loops indefinitely.

Any idea why this can be happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by, "it's not a template, it's actually a shortcode"? Also, in what context, and/or in what template file, are you using `blog.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your blog.php file you need to declare `<?php wp_head(); ?>` without this the loop will not work and only so many items within `$post` will be available to you.